# Finding key:value pair for minimum value in R list

Tags: r, list

I have a list - `distances` in R.  What is the simplest way to return the key-value pair in the list that contains the minimum value?

I understand the actual minimum value can be found with `min(unlist(distances))`, but is there a one line solution to finding the corresponding key and minimum value in the list?  The output should be something like `[[2]] , 36.40016`

```
distances
[[1]]
         [,1]
[1,] 144.7077

[[2]]
         [,1]
[1,] 36.40016


> dput(distances)
list(structure(144.707681719953, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), structure(36.4001632486179, .Dim = c(1L, 
1L)))
```

Comment: Try `min(do.call(rbind,YourList))`

Comment: Except that does not return the key

Comment: `[[2]]` is not the key here. It is the position. If you do `distances[-1]` it changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which.min` to get the index of minimum value after unlisting :

```
which.min(unlist(distances))
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a single row/column matrix, we can directly use `which.min`

```
which.min(distances)
#[1] 2
```

NOTE: `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes.   If the `list` is of length 1 for each element, we can directly apply the `which.min`